# Bug: VS 2017 ASP.NET Core app published to IIS [same machine]

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2016, iis-10, asp.net-core-1.1

First creating a new project in VS 2017 with template of ASP.NET Core (and individual authentication) does not have a web.config; yet is added upon publishing the app to C:\inetpub\wwwroot (on new install of Window server 2016, and VS on same machine).

When published, it fails to open a web page giving a "500 - Internal server error" page display. Going into IIS Manager after clicking on mySite in left panel, trying to click on anything in the middle panel for the hosted web site fails to open with this error:

[image]

As you can also see it gives no information into the actual error.
So not sure why it's looking to `\\?\C:` for the web.config file? I believe if I can get help resolving this the web page should load; as it does load in development. As stated this issue is occurring on just deployment of a basic ASP.NET Core template; but it also is doing the same thing with my previous web site created with VS 2015 Community ported over to VS 2017 (with required update to it by VS)

The web.config file, which is only in the published app folder and not the development project folders, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Laier-IT.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issue is typical of an IIS configuration that is not configured for .Net Core.

In order to host .Net Core applications in IIS it is necessary to install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle.

For detailed instructions on installing the .Net Core Windows Server Hosting bundle checkout the [Microsoft documentation on installing .Net Core Windows Server Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle).

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) also provides extensive information on deploying .Net Core to IIS and various other HTTP Servers.

Additionally you need to set the .Net CLR to no managed code in the application pool settings:[image: CLR should be set to No Managed Code]

Comment: Typical? As I never had this issue using VS 2015 Community. Ok well tried loading ".NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle" and received an installation error for Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.4 & 1.1.1 Windows Server Hosting of "Another version of this product is already installed."

Comment: The linked documentation provides some good troubleshooting info. are you able to show us the contents of your web.config file?Can you run the application from the command line e.g. dotnet myapplication.dll?

Comment: Have you changed the application pool's CLR version to No Managed Code?

Comment: I update the question with the web.config script. I also tried the dotnet cmd command and received "Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down." Which I then typed localhost:5000 into my browser. This works fine but of course that is local and not being called through the IIS service from outside the network.

Comment: web.config looks good...and this is the behaviour we would expect from your app running from CLR...which reaffirms that the issue has to do with the IIS integration. Have you changed the application pool's CLR version to No Managed Code?

Comment: Ok I did the change in the application pool's CLR version from v4.0 to No managed Code and it worked. Please update your answer with this and maybe an explanation as to why it would fix the issue and I will upvote and select your answer

Comment: Can you please explain what that does and why it fixed my issue?

Comment: The .Net CLR version is used to instantiate the correct .Net runtime - however when running .Net Core website we are just using IIS to proxy through to the Kestrel Webserver via the dotnet executable. I am uncertain why leaving this set to a version of the .Net CLR results in an error.